# how to download using weather data function many proporties exactly.

Tags: functions

how to download using weather data function many proporties exactly. 
Example  WeatherData["WMO44292", "Humidity", "Pressure", "Temperature", \
{{2005, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {2015, 1, 1, 0, 0}}] .

Comment: like this?

`WeatherData[
   "WMO44292", #, {{2005, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {2015, 1, 1, 0, 
     0}}] & /@ {"Humidity", "Pressure", "Temperature"}`

Answer (score 4):

Here the answer to your question posted in your comment in following steps:

1) Retrieve Weather data and assign to dset

```
dset = WeatherData[
     "WMO44292", #, {{1956, 8, 2, 12, 0, 0}, {1957, 8, 2, 12, 0, 
       0}}] & /@ {"Humidity", "Pressure", "Temperature"}
```

2) Restructure list

```
dset1 = DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten[#, 1] & /@  ( dset // Transpose )
```

3) Now create a nested list

```
  (d \[Function] Fold[Append[{#1}, #2] &, First@d, Rest@d]) /@ dset1
```

resulting in the list structure you asked for in your comments.

Hereafter, this gives you a table with all the properties and values available for the location you have specified.

```
    {WeatherData["Properties"], 
   WeatherData ["WMO44292", #] & /@ WeatherData["Properties"]} // 
  Transpose // TableForm
```

brr... must be cold in Mongolia :)

Comment: result is `{1956, 8, 2, 12, 0, 0}, 0.421}`. I want `{1956, 8, 2, 12, 0, 0}, 0.421},1041},17}`. My english is very bad. :(

Comment: I need No all proporties. Huminity, pressure and temperature.

Comment: Today snowing and raining in Mongolia. Yesterday has spring. Today have winter. kkk :)

Comment: I think I understood your question in your comments and I posted a possible solution at the begin of my answer. Is it what you was looking for ? :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you  :)

Comment: Your answer  code is one day information. My project is `{{1956, 8, 2, 12, 0, 0}, {1990, 1, 20, 12, 0, 
       0}}]` . I need between this two years information.

Comment: Example `{{1956, 8, 2, 12, 0, 0}, 0.421},1041},17}, {1956, 8, 3, 12, 0, 0}, 0.461},1042},17}}]`

Comment: @tegshjargal, Thanks for insisting.... I have modified my answer to be generic that works now for any period.....if you are happy with solution then vote for penguins......hi,hi,hi

Comment: @tegshjargal,  ..and please mark question as answered, if solution works for you.....good luck with your weather analysis. :)